# Facebook How to get events id from user added pixel to a website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, pixel, facebook-pixel

We need Event Name and Event Id for deduplication.
I have an app that provides the Conversion API data for clients. In case my clients have Pixel Script already set up on their websites I need to have the list of Events name with ids to use in my Conversion API request to have deduplication working fine.

I used the Facebook Pixel Helper Chrome extension which is listing all events with ids and other details. So how it is possible out of that extension?

I have a script that can be added to the client's websites, I can have some JavaScript to do this for me, but how it would be possible?

[image]

Comment: My guess would be, the browser extension probably just listens to the requests made by the page, and filters out the FB pixels ones.

Comment: @CBroe Do you have any idea how to access those requests?